# Pass a dictionary inside the initial API request in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, url, python-requests

What is the best way to achieve the request of this API.

During the request, I want to specify the 'first', 'last' and 'organization'.

The problem i am facing is the dictionary inside the URL after '?person=', which return an Error in the terminal telling me to only use a string.

Please find the api request below:

```
url = "http://api.foo.com/search/?person={%"names":[{"first":"foo","last":"foo"}],"jobs":[{"organization":"foo"}]}&key=foo"
```

Below is the structure of the api.

```
Person : 
     -first
     -last
Jobs: - organization
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try converting your dict using `json.dumps()` into a string before passing it in the url. I guess that would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are doing good,

I believe the best way is either to use the library urllib

For example:

```
import urllib
mydict  = {"person":{"names":[{"first":"foo","last":"foo"}],"jobs":[{"organization":"foo"}]}}
url = "http://api.foo.com/search/?person={}&key=foo".format(urllib.urlencode(mydict))
```

End value will look like:

```
http://api.foo.com/search/?person=%7B%27jobs%27%3A+%5B%7B%27organization%27%3A+%27foo%27%7D%5D%2C+%27names%27%3A+%5B%7B%27last%27%3A+%27foo%27%2C+%27first%27%3A+%27foo%27%7D%5D%7D&key=foo
```

Which when you look at the request will look like:

[image]

If you use:

```
import urlparse
urlparse.parse_qs('http://api.foo.com/search/?person=%7B%27jobs%27%3A+%5B%7B%27organization%27%3A+%27foo%27%7D%5D%2C+%27names%27%3A+%5B%7B%27last%27%3A+%27foo%27%2C+%27first%27%3A+%27foo%27%7D%5D%7D&key=foo')

#{'http://api.foo.com/search/?person': ["{'jobs': [{'organization': 'foo'}], 'names': [{'last': 'foo', 'first': 'foo'}]}"],
#'key': ['foo']}
```

Have a lovely day,

My best regards.

G